# Flask application alongside Node.JS application

Tags: python, node.js, flask

I wrote a Flask web application for a system that our company uses. However, we have another web application, which is running on Node.JS. The "problem" is that my colleague writes everything on node, while I write everything in Python.

We want to implement both applications on one webpage - for example:

1. My application will run on example.com/assistant
2. His application will run on example.com/app1 and example.com/app2

How can we do this? Can we somehow implement the templates that I use with his templates and vice-versa?

Thank you in advance!

V

Comment: In a word, no. You and your colleague are going to have to get on the same page here.

Answer (score 0):

**Serving different apps from the same domain**

You can use [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) for directing requests to specific service based on ACL rules.

You could use `path_beg` rule, to direct any request beginning with specific path to be directed to corresponding server. See example below.

*/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg*

```
# only relevant part of the config file
# assumes all apps are on one machine
frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  acl py_app1 path_beg /assistant
  acl node_app1 path_beg /app1
  acl node_app2 path_beg /app2
  default_backend main_servers

backend py_app1
  server flask_app 127.0.0.1:5000

backend node_app1
  server nodejs1 127.0.0.1:4001

backend node_app2
  server nodejs2 127.0.0.1:4002

backend main_servers
  server other1 127.0.0.1:3000 # nginx, apache, or whatever
```

**Sharing template code between apps**

This would be harder, as you would need to both agree on some kind of format, which needs to be language and framework-agnostic, and probably logic-less.

Mustache claims to be *"framework-agnostic way to render logic-free views"*. I used it sparringly a few years ago so this one is first that came to mind, however you should do more research on this, maybe there is some better fit.

- [Python implementation](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache)
- [JS implementation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

The problem would be to actually keep the templates always in sync with apps, and not break functionality of the views. If a template changes then you would need to test all apps that use this template file. Also, you probably will block one another from updating your apps at different times, because if one of you change the template files, then you must come to a consensus, update all relevant apps, and deploy them at one time.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense! We will try tomorrow the haproxy approach. If this does not work, we will see if we can have something else. Thanks a lot!